# Merge two array in php

Tags: php

I have two arrays

```
$array1= array([6] = 6 [9] = 9 [60] = 60 );

$array2 = array([01] = 01 [03] = 03 [02] = 0);
```

I want this result:

```
$array_new = array([6] = 6 [9] = 9 [60] = 60 [01] = 01 [03] = 03 [02] = 0);
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: have you tryed array_merge? maybe search "array merge" in google?

Comment: Question shows *no* research effort.

Comment: Did you even try `$array1 + $array2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function:

```
$array_new = array_merge($array1, $array2)
```

Comment: Thanks but array_merge give me $array_new = [fed_state] =array
        (
            [01] =01
            [03] = 03
            [02] = 0
            [0] = 6
            [1] = 9
            [2] = 60
        );

Comment: To preserve index order, use ``+`` operator as @meager noted. See http://ideone.com/kk3yiT for working example.

Comment: Thanks Kita, + operator is working properly for me.